# Using UDP Server with Delphi

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

I have a project made with Delphi 7. I'm getting an error when I compile with Delphi XE7. The Indy component kit was used in the project. I think the problem is due to differences between Indy 9 and Indy 10. I have tried many methods to solve the problem, but I have not been successful. How can I solve this problem?

```
procedure TRealTimeForm.btnListenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
   FUDPServer.DefaultPort := StrToInt(edtPort.Text);
   FUDPServer.OnUDPRead:=UDPServerUDPRead;
   FUDPServer.Active := True;
   btnListen.Enabled := False;
 except
   on E:Exception do
    ShowMessage(e.Message);
 end;
end;

procedure TRealTimeForm.UDPServerUDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream;
  ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  i: integer;
  lReceiveData: array of Byte;
  sDIN: string;
  year,month,day,hour,minute,second: integer;
  rec: IRecordExt;
  iInt64: Int64;
begin
{
  [0-7]: for check data valid, you can ignore.
[8-23]: these 16 bytes are what you want is the Log entity. The structure is:
Size of structure: 16 bytes
Structure:
//
  UINT64    UserID      //8 bytes
//
  UINT32  Year    :  7;  //7 bits, MAX: 127, base on 2000.
  UINT32  Month  :  4;  //4 bits
  UINT32  Day    :  5;  //5 bits
  UINT32  Action  :  4;    //4 bits
  UINT32  Status  :  5;  //5 bits
  UINT32  JobCode  :  7;  //7 bits, MAX: 127
  UINT32  Antipassback  :1;  //1 bit
  UINT32  DeviceID:  14;  //14 bits, MAX: 16383
  UINT32  Hour  :  5;  //5 bits
  UINT32  Minute  :  6;  //6 bits
  UINT32  Second  :  6;  //6 bits
//
//
[24-31]: device physical address.
}
  try
    if AData.Size < GLogLen then
    begin
      SetLength(lReceiveData,AData.Size);
      AData.ReadBuffer(lReceiveData[0],AData.Size);
      ShowDataLog(lReceiveData);
      Exit;
    end;
    SetLength(lReceiveData,GLogLen);
    AData.ReadBuffer(lReceiveData[0],GLogLen);
    ShowDataLog(lReceiveData);
    if not IsCorectGLog(lReceiveData) then
      Exit;
    rec := CoRecordExt.Create;

    iInt64 := 0;
    for i := 8 to 15 do
    begin
      iInt64 := iInt64 + lReceiveData[i] shl ((i-8) * 8);
    end;
    sDIN := IntToStr(iInt64);
    year := lReceiveData[16] and $7F + 2000;
    month := ((lReceiveData[16] + lReceiveData[17] shl 8) shr 7) and $0F;
    day := (lReceiveData[17] + lReceiveData[18] shl 8) shr 3 and $1F;
    hour := (lReceiveData[21] + lReceiveData[22] shl 8) shr 7 and $1F;
    minute := (lReceiveData[22] + lReceiveData[23] shl 8) shr 4 and $3F;
    second := lReceiveData[23] shr 2 and $3F;

    rec.DIN := sDIN;
    rec.Clock := EncodeDate(year,month,day) + EncodeTime(hour,minute,second,0);
    rec.Verify := (lReceiveData[18] + lReceiveData[19] shl 8) shr 4 and $1F;
    rec.Action := lReceiveData[18] and $0F;
    rec.DN := (lReceiveData[20] + lReceiveData[21] shl 8 + lReceiveData[22] shl 16) shr 1 and $3FFF;
    AddRecord(rec);
    FUDPServer.SendBuffer(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,lReceiveData[0],GLogLen);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      mmoDataLog.Lines.Add(e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The parts that give errors:

```
FUDPServer.OnUDPRead:=UDPServerUDPRead;
FUDPServer.SendBuffer(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,lReceiveData[0],GLogLen);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Indy 10, the signature of the `OnUDPRead` event and the `SendBuffer()` method have both changed. Which you would have easily seen if you looked at the new declarations.

Also, in both Indy 9 and 10, you should be sending the response back to the sender using the `SendTo()` method of the `TIdSocketHandle` object that `OnUDPRead` gives you, not the `SendBuffer()` method of `TIdUDPServer`, which will use the 1st `TIdSocketHandle` in the server's  `Bindings` collection, which may or may not be the correct socket to send with in a multi-homed system.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TRealTimeForm.btnListenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    FUDPServer.DefaultPort := StrToInt(edtPort.Text);
    FUDPServer.OnUDPRead := UDPServerUDPRead;
    FUDPServer.Active := True;
    btnListen.Enabled := False;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TRealTimeForm.UDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  i: integer;
  sDIN: string;
  year, month, day, hour, minute, second: Integer;
  rec: IRecordExt;
  iInt64: Int64;
begin
{
  [0-7]: for check data valid, you can ignore.
[8-23]: these 16 bytes are what you want is the Log entity. The structure is:
Size of structure: 16 bytes
Structure:
//
  UINT64    UserID      //8 bytes
//
  UINT32  Year    :  7;  //7 bits, MAX: 127, base on 2000.
  UINT32  Month  :  4;  //4 bits
  UINT32  Day    :  5;  //5 bits
  UINT32  Action  :  4;    //4 bits
  UINT32  Status  :  5;  //5 bits
  UINT32  JobCode  :  7;  //7 bits, MAX: 127
  UINT32  Antipassback  :1;  //1 bit
  UINT32  DeviceID:  14;  //14 bits, MAX: 16383
  UINT32  Hour  :  5;  //5 bits
  UINT32  Minute  :  6;  //6 bits
  UINT32  Second  :  6;  //6 bits
//
//
[24-31]: device physical address.
}
  try
    if Length(AData) < GLogLen then
    begin
      ShowDataLog(AData);
      Exit;
    end;

    ShowDataLog(AData);
    if not IsCorectGLog(AData) then
      Exit;

    rec := CoRecordExt.Create;

    iInt64 := 0;
    for i := 8 to 15 do
    begin
      iInt64 := iInt64 + AData[i] shl ((i-8) * 8);
    end;
    sDIN := IntToStr(iInt64);
    year := AData[16] and $7F + 2000;
    month := ((AData[16] + AData[17] shl 8) shr 7) and $0F;
    day := (AData[17] + AData[18] shl 8) shr 3 and $1F;
    hour := (AData[21] + AData[22] shl 8) shr 7 and $1F;
    minute := (AData[22] + AData[23] shl 8) shr 4 and $3F;
    second := AData[23] shr 2 and $3F;

    rec.DIN := sDIN;
    rec.Clock := EncodeDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second,. 0);
    rec.Verify := (AData[18] + AData[19] shl 8) shr 4 and $1F;
    rec.Action := AData[18] and $0F;
    rec.DN := (AData[20] + AData[21] shl 8 + AData[22] shl 16) shr 1 and $3FFF;
    AddRecord(rec);
    ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP, ABinding.PeerPort, AData, 0, GLogLen);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      mmoDataLog.Lines.Add(e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: hello. I am grateful for your help. I'm getting the same error. FUDPServer.OnUDPRead:=UDPServerUDPRead; ([dcc32 Error] RealTimeFrm.pas(68): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TIdUDPListenerThread' and 'TObject')

Comment: @CihadŞükrüYaşar the `OnUDPRead` event is declared very differently in the two Indy versions. In Indy 9, it is: `TUDPReadEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle) of object;`. In Indy 10, it is: `TUDPReadEvent = procedure(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle) of object;` You can't share the same code with both Indy versions. If you want to compile the code in both Delphi versions, you will have to `{$IFDEF}` the code. If that is not what you are trying to do, then please expand your example into a [mcve].